# Jenkins process high cpu usage 800%.

Tags: jenkins, cpu-usage

I have installed jenkins version 1.614 on ubuntu 12.04 with configuration - 32 GB ram, 2 TB hdd and 8 CPU cores. Currently Jenkins has 594 jobs added. 
In normal condition when no job is running cpu usage is 0% but When I start any job build cpu usage suddenly reaches 700-800%.

Following are the stats for cpu usage.

```
top - 06:29:55 up 160 days, 17:43,  3 users,  load average: 4.27, 2.54, 2.43
Tasks: 123 total,   2 running, 118 sleeping,   0 stopped,   3 zombie
Cpu0  : 96.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 95.7%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.0%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  : 96.7%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  2.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  : 92.0%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  7.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  : 96.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  : 96.7%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  2.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  : 97.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32809732k total, 26551884k used,  6257848k free,   481144k buffers
Swap: 16768892k total,     8376k used, 16760516k free, 15064772k cached


 3852 jenkins   20   0 12.5g 8.1g  21m S  774 26.0   2095:06 java                                                                              
   14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   5:05.81 kworker/2:0                                                                       
   67 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   4:51.63 kworker/3:1                                                                       
  399 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   4:12.45 jbd2/md2-8                                                                        
 1251 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   6:02.19 flush-9:2                                                                         
 6754 appster   20   0 1052m 152m 2244 S    0  0.5 317:39.39 statsd                                                                            
    1 root      20   0 24196 1528  832 S    0  0.0   0:18.22 init
```

I have also deleted job builds older than 30 days and current running job build is also small job, Still cpu usage is very high.

Comment: Jenkins process is running multiple thread for java. I executed this command  top -c -H -p $(pgrep -d, -f "java")  , for this command its showing multiple thread of /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war.  Dont know why jenkins creating multiple threads.

Comment: This also happens to me. When the load gets high, some parts of the web interface stops responding, for example, when creating a new node.

Comment: what is your question?